# With PyGTK/win32, how do I place a new window near its parent but not off-screen?

Tags: python, windows, gtk, pygtk

With *PyGTK* running on *Windows*, I want to have a new window pop up near a parent window, but never off-screen.

I observed the behavior I want in *Microsoft Wordpad* in both *Windows 7* and *Windows XP*. If you make the window very small and move it to the bottom right of the desktop, right click in the text field, and open the *Paragraph* menu, the dialog pops up fully visible. This happens even if the *Wordpad* window is partially off-screen. The child dialog does not pop up in a fixed position relative to the main window. It just pops up close, and fully visible.

My application consists of a main screen which spawns child windows that block the rest of the application until the user is finished using them. The user may have to open and close many child windows in sequence, so I want them to appear near where they click on the button, so the user doesn't have to move the mouse all over the screen.

I tried using *gtk.WIN_POS_MOUSE*, but when the main menu is near an edge of the screen; the child window that spawns often ends up partially off-screen.

I would expect that a call to *set_transient_for(main_menu)* on a child window should inform *Windows* that I want my window to be near its parent. However, *Windows* just places it at the top left of the desktop -- not even necessarily on the same screen as the main menu.

The following code will demonstrate the problem by popping up a window at the bottom left of your screen that contains a button which spawns a subwindow when clicked:

```
import gtk

class MyWindow(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("delete-event",self.on_delete_event)
        button = gtk.Button("Open Subwindow")
        button.connect("clicked",self.open_sub_window)
        self.add(button)
        self.set_gravity(gtk.gdk.GRAVITY_SOUTH_EAST)
        self.show_all()
        width, height = self.get_size()
        self.move(gtk.gdk.screen_width() - width, gtk.gdk.screen_height() - height)

    def on_delete_event(self, widget=None, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def open_sub_window(self, widget=None, data=None):
        w = gtk.Window()
        w.set_size_request(200,200)
        w.set_transient_for(self)
        w.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ON_PARENT)
        w.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyWindow()
    gtk.main()
```

As you can see, the sub_window shows up partially off-screen.
If you comment out the line *w.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ON_PARENT)* you will see that the *Windows* window manager just places the subwindow at the very top left of the desktop. Not very useful!

Is there a way to get the desired behavior without resorting to manually managing Window positioning by checking what location the window ends up at and then moving the window to a fully off-screen position?

**UPDATE:** 
I filed a bug report for pyGTK on Feb 23, 2011: http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643138

It has not yet had any responses from the devs or other users. If you are having this problem please chime in on the bug so it gets fixed (or so that we might get a workaround).

Comment: Note: If I set the subwindow gravity to SOUTH_EAST with w.set_gravity(gtk.gdk.GRAVITY_SOUTH_EAST) before w.set_position(...), the problem is partially alleviated; the window won't get positioned beyond the bottom right corner of the current screen. However, it can still appear below the taskbar, and worse, with the window decoration beyond the top or left edges of the desktop.

Comment: I suppose that on most linux/unix systems the window manager would handle this automatically, and it's not as well-tested in Windows...  Maybe you should file a bug-report and/or fix it in Gtk yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a GTK+ bug. The window manager (Windows Explorer in my case) is responsible for window placement. Gtk only provides positioning hints; it doesn't know the size of the decorations applied by Explorer, so Gtk alone can't be used to position a window properly. This is in the documentation for GtkWindow's get_size() method:
"[...] window manager decorations (aka the window frame or border) [...] are not drawn by GTK+ and GTK+ has no reliable method of determining their size."
My question regards using Gtk+ to influence the behavior of the window manager to get the desired result.

Comment: Well, the Windows GTK port should influence the behavior of the window manager in a useful way so that you don't have to. I would file a bug report if I were you.

Comment: I filed a bug report: http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643138